# Jquery multiple slider: ui.slider.handle start value?

Tags: jquery, slider, handler

I am facing some problems: I am using a multiple ui slider. It gathers data from a database. So on opening the page it already has a starting and ending value.

I am using two "boxes" above the handlers to show the current value. They are moving with the handler.

But: I figured out how to show the starting values on page load but can't get the css values of the handlers to show the boxes above them right from the start.

Code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#<?php echo $site; ?>").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 16,
        max: 1024,
        values: [ < ? php echo $from; ? > , < ? php echo $to; ? > ],
        step: < ? php echo $step; ? > ,
        slide : function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.values[1] < 1024) {
                $("#<?php echo $fi; ?>").html(ui.values[0] + " kbps");
                $("#<?php echo $la; ?>").html(ui.values[1] + " kbps");
            }
            else {
                $("#<?php echo $fi; ?>").html(ui.values[0] + " kbps");
                $("#<?php echo $la; ?>").html(ui.values[1] + " kbps <");
            }

            $("#<?php echo $field; ?>").val(ui.values[0] + '-' + ui.values[1])

            alert($(this).children('.ui-slider-handle').first().css('left'));

            var offset1 = $(this).children('.ui-slider-handle').first().css('left');
            var offset2 = $(this).children('.ui-slider-handle').last().css('left');

            $("#<?php echo $fi; ?>").css('left', offset1);
            $("#<?php echo $la; ?>").css('left', offset2);
        },

    });
});
```

Hope you can help :)

EDIT:

```
 $("#<?php echo $fi; ?>").css('left', offset1);
 $("#<?php echo $la; ?>").css('left', offset2);
```

The mistake must be above. offset1+2 got the wrong css value (start and end of slider bar).

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is this a range slider ? Provide an image of what kind of slider it is, or explain what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

here's an image:

http://i47.tinypic.com/w1ybua.jpg

As you can see, the boxes aren't above the sliders but on the start and ending of the bar. How do I change this on initializing the slider?